# Custom profile information with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an application with ASP.NET MVC 4, with the Entity Framework, that uses Windows authentication (though it wouldn't be out of question to change it to organizational accounts). This means that I get the user's domain and name. However, I'd like to be able to save additional information about my users than what I can query from Active Directory.

When you use "individual user accounts", Visual Studio will create for you a user entity that you can extend to fit your needs. It can be accessed globally. However, when you use Windows authentication, this User property is an instance of IPrincipal, which clearly isn't quite as easy to extend.

Now, I can get some of the information I want from the Active Directory, but I'd like my users to be able to add in some more. For now I have a distinct Person entity that I query from controllers and add to ViewBag when I need it, but it doesn't feel quite as convenient.

Is there a middle ground between Windows authentication and individual accounts where my users would have single sign-on, but where I'd still be able to conveniently have more profile fields than just their NT name?